# Issues using nodemon with docker on different hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nodemon

I have a docker-compose script running a dev environment on my machine (macOS 10.14.5) using nodemon - everything working as expected. When I run the same docker-compose script on a different machine, nodemon no longer reloads the client service. Both machines are running the same docker and docker-compose versions (and the same macOS version):

```
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

The docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server/
    command: /usr/app/node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/App.js
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client/
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

and referenced dockerfiles:

server

```
FROM node:9.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -qy

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and client

```
FROM node:9.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I have tried changing user permissions of the app folder on the other host machine but the issues continues.
Any suggestions to help fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide error logs.

Comment: The error I'm getting is no hot-reloading for Nodemon - I don't know of any error logs that would create.